# One2One relationship in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, frameworks, entity

I am interested how to achieve one 2 one relationship between two tables using Entity Framework without using Fluent API, just using Data Annotations. Is this possible ? If yes could someone give me a sample code for this ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just curious, why not use the fluent API?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, ForeignKeyAttribute (FW 4.5) will help you.